# how can i find what type of encription this is? im looking for the algorithums and the modes. this is a javascript code

Tags: encryption, javascript, decryption

javascript: var _0x1166=['\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20','\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72','\x6b\x65\x79\x64\x6f\x77\x6e','\x6b\x65\x79\x43\x6f\x64\x65','\x6e\x67\x2d\x62\x69\x6e\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x2d\x6d\x69\x6e\x69\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x2d\x62\x6c\x75\x65\x20\x6c\x65\x76\x65\x6c\x62\x74\x6e\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68','\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65','\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6c\x65\x64','\x48\x41\x43\x4b\x45\x44\x20\x41\x43\x43\x4f\x55\x4e\x54\x53\x3a\x0a\x41\x52\x2d\x36\x37\x37\x37\x30\x20\x7e\x20\x53\x63\x72\x75\x62\x35\x39\x0a\x7a\x6f\x2d\x39\x38\x36\x30\x34\x20\x7e\x20\x62\x72\x69\x63\x6b\x31\x33\x0a\x6d\x64\x2d\x37\x30\x31\x35\x35\x20\x7e\x20\x64\x75\x63\x6b\x31\x34\x0a\x41\x4d\x2d\x31\x30\x34\x33\x31\x38\x38\x20\x7e\x20\x73\x61\x6e\x64\x36\x39\x0a\x4a\x4d\x2d\x36\x39\x37\x31\x37\x20\x7e\x20\x67\x6f\x61\x6c\x39\x37\x0a\x4d\x4b\x2d\x39\x30\x35\x38\x36\x20\x7e\x20\x73\x68\x61\x64\x65\x37\x37\x0a\x41\x50\x2d\x31\x30\x32\x38\x30\x31\x20\x7e\x20\x73\x6f\x69\x6c\x37\x30\x0a\x59\x65\x73\x20\x61\x6c\x6c\x20\x6f\x66\x20\x74\x68\x65\x6d\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6b\x20\x3a\x50\x20','\x66\x61\x63\x65\x2d\x62\x67','\x69\x6e\x6e\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4d\x4c','\x3c\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x3d\x27\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x72\x65\x6c\x61\x74\x69\x76\x65\x3b\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x31\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3b\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3a\x20\x31\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x2d\x6f\x72\x69\x67\x69\x6e\x3a\x20\x30\x70\x78\x20\x30\x70\x78\x20\x30\x70\x78\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x73\x63\x61\x6c\x65\x28\x30\x2e\x35\x29\x3b\x27\x20\x62\x61\x73\x65\x2d\x75\x72\x6c\x3d\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3a\x2f\x2f\x77\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x63\x64\x6e\x2e\x6d\x61\x74\x68\x6c\x65\x74\x69\x63\x73\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x66\x61\x63\x65\x4d\x61\x6b\x65\x72\x2f\x53\x74\x75\x64\x65\x6e\x74\x2f\x70\x6e\x67\x73\x2f\x27\x20\x66\x61\x63\x65\x2d\x73\x65\x74\x74\x69\x6e\x67\x3d\x27\x6d\x7c\x33\x33\x7c\x31\x7c\x31\x7c\x33\x7c\x33\x7c\x31\x31\x7c\x31\x33\x7c\x37\x7c\x32\x37\x7c\x39\x7c\x30\x7c\x33\x7c\x38\x32\x7c\x39\x7c\x38\x35\x7c\x30\x27\x20\x73\x63\x61\x6c\x65\x3d\x27\x30\x2e\x35\x27\x20\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x3d\x27\x6e\x67\x2d\x69\x73\x6f\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x2d\x73\x63\x6f\x70\x65\x27\x3e\x20\x3c\x69\x6d\x67\x20\x6e\x67\x2d\x73\x72\x63\x3d\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3a\x2f\x2f\x77\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x63\x64\x6e\x2e\x6d\x61\x74\x68\x6c\x65\x74\x69\x63\x73\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x66\x61\x63\x65\x4d\x61\x6b\x65\x72\x2f\x53\x74\x75\x64\x65\x6e\x74\x2f\x70\x6e\x67\x73\x2f\x62\x67\x2d\x38\x35\x2e\x70\x6e\x67\x27\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x3d\x27\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x61\x62\x73\x6f\x6c\x75\x74\x65\x27\x20\x6e\x67\x2d\x73\x68\x6f\x77\x3d\x27\x73\x68\x6f\x77\x42\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x27\x20\x61\x6c\x74\x3d\x27\x27\x20\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x3d\x27\x27\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3d\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3a\x2f\x2f\x6f\x72\x69\x67\x30\x30\x2e\x64\x65\x76\x69\x61\x6e\x74\x61\x72\x74\x2e\x6e\x65\x74\x2f\x39\x61\x31\x62\x2f\x66\x2f\x32\x30\x31\x33\x2f\x33\x34\x34\x2f\x64\x2f\x39\x2f\x63\x61\x74\x5f\x65\x79\x65\x5f\x32\x30\x30\x78\x32\x30\x30\x5f\x5f\x5f\x67\x69\x66\x5f\x62\x79\x5f\x72\x6f\x62\x62\x69\x65\x62\x72\x2d\x64\x36\x78\x66\x71\x6e\x78\x2e\x67\x69\x66\x27\x3e','\x62\x6f\x64\x79','\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65','\x75\x72\x6c\x28\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3a\x2f\x2f\x6d\x65\x64\x69\x61\x31\x2e\x67\x69\x70\x68\x79\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x6d\x65\x64\x69\x61\x2f\x78\x54\x69\x54\x6e\x78\x70\x51\x33\x67\x68\x50\x69\x42\x32\x48\x70\x36\x2f\x67\x69\x70\x68\x79\x2e\x67\x69\x66\x27\x29','\x75\x72\x6c\x28\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3a\x2f\x2f\x6d\x65\x64\x69\x61\x2e\x67\x69\x70\x68\x79\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x6d\x65\x64\x69\x61\x2f\x4e\x37\x4f\x51\x58\x66\x64\x75\x71\x79\x52\x48\x4f\x2f\x32\x30\x30\x2e\x67\x69\x66\x27\x29','\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x49\x6d\x61\x67\x65','\x62\x74\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x53\x69\x7a\x65\x20\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6f\x6e\x5f\x76\x73\x43\x6f\x6d\x70\x75\x74\x65\x72','\x75\x72\x6c\x28\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3a\x2f\x2f\x74\x68\x65\x6c\x69\x6e\x64\x61\x63\x6c\x69\x66\x66\x6f\x72\x64\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x69\x6d\x61\x67\x65\x73\x2f\x62\x61\x6c\x6c\x5f\x73\x70\x69\x6e\x5f\x32\x32\x33\x2e\x67\x69\x66\x27\x29','\x62\x74\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x53\x69\x7a\x65\x20\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6f\x6e\x5f\x76\x73\x4d\x79\x43\x6c\x61\x73\x73','\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64','\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64','\x6d\x79\x41\x75\x64\x69\x6f','\x6d\x6f\x7a','\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74','\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68','\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x41\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x46\x72\x61\x6d\x65','\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x41\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x46\x72\x61\x6d\x65','\x63\x61\x6e\x63\x65\x6c\x41\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x46\x72\x61\x6d\x65','\x43\x61\x6e\x63\x65\x6c\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x41\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x46\x72\x61\x6d\x65','\x6d\x61\x78','\x73\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6d\x65\x6f\x75\x74','\x74\x64\x66\x77\x49\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x20\x31\x73\x20\x69\x6e\x66\x69\x6e\x69\x74\x65\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x2d\x69\x6e\x2d\x6f\x75\x74','\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d','\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x74\x44\x6f\x77\x6e','\x20\x35\x73\x20\x69\x6e\x66\x69\x6e\x69\x74\x65\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x2d\x69\x6e\x2d\x6f\x75\x74','\x64\x69\x76','\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x7a\x49\x6e\x64\x65\x78','\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74','\x74\x6f\x70','\x6f\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79','\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6c\x64','\x6f\x6e\x6d\x6f\x75\x73\x65\x6f\x76\x65\x72','\x6f\x6e\x6d\x6f\x75\x73\x65\x6f\x75\x74','\x6f\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79\x20\x30\x2e\x33\x73\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x2d\x69\x6e\x2d\x6f\x75\x74','\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74','\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74','\x73\x72\x63','\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3a\x2f\x2f\x77\x77\x77\x2e\x79\x6f\x75\x74\x75\x62\x65\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x5f\x61\x70\x69','\x74\x64\x66\x77','\x32\x30\x30','\x33\x30\x35','\x48\x4d\x55\x44\x56\x4d\x69\x49\x54\x4f\x55','\x6f\x6e\x59\x6f\x75\x54\x75\x62\x65\x49\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x41\x50\x49\x52\x65\x61\x64\x79','\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79','\x67\x65\x74\x43\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6e\x74\x54\x69\x6d\x65','\x6c\x6f\x67','\x64\x61\x74\x61','\x70\x78\x2c','\x70\x78\x29\x3b\x20','\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x28','\x20\x7d\x20','\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6f\x64\x65','\x2d\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74\x2d\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x28','\x70\x78\x29\x20\x72\x6f\x74\x61\x74\x65','\x64\x65\x67\x29\x3b\x20','\x20\x7b\x20','\x40\x2d\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74\x2d\x6b\x65\x79\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x73\x20\x74\x64\x66\x77\x49\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x20\x7b\x20','\x40\x6b\x65\x79\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x73\x20\x74\x64\x66\x77\x49\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x20\x7b\x20','\x40\x2d\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74\x2d\x6b\x65\x79\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x73\x20\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x74\x44\x6f\x77\x6e','\x40\x6b\x65\x79\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65\x73\x20\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x74\x44\x6f\x77\x6e','\x2e\x74\x64\x66\x77\x5f\x69\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x20\x7b\x20\x2d\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74\x2d\x61\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x74\x64\x66\x77\x20\x31\x73\x20\x69\x6e\x66\x69\x6e\x69\x74\x65\x3b\x20\x61\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x74\x64\x66\x77\x20\x31\x73\x20\x69\x6e\x66\x69\x6e\x69\x74\x65\x3b\x20\x7d\x20','\x74\x65\x78\x74\x43\x6f\x6e\x74\x65\x6e\x74','\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x74\x79\x70\x65','\x63\x61\x6c\x6c','\x69\x6d\x67','\x63\x6f\x6e\x63\x61\x74','\x73\x6c\x69\x63\x65','\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x53\x65\x6c\x65\x63\x74\x6f\x72\x41\x6c\x6c','\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x4c\x69\x73\x74','\x61\x64\x64','\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64','\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74\x41\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65','\x74\x64\x66\x77\x5f\x69\x6e\x74\x72\x6f','\x74\x64\x66\x77\x5f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x54\x44\x46\x57','\x75\x6e\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6e\x65\x64','\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x2c\x20\x62\x6f\x64\x79','\x63\x73\x73','\x3c\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x3d\x22\x63\x75\x72\x73\x6f\x72\x3a\x6e\x6f\x6e\x65\x3b\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x30\x30\x30\x3b\x20\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64\x3b\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3a\x20\x31\x30\x30\x25\x3b\x20\x6c\x65\x66\x74\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x62\x6f\x74\x74\x6f\x6d\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x62\x6f\x72\x64\x65\x72\x2d\x74\x6f\x70\x3a\x20\x31\x70\x78\x20\x73\x6f\x6c\x69\x64\x20\x23\x66\x66\x66\x3b\x22\x3e\x3c\x2f\x64\x69\x76\x3e','\x63\x6c\x69\x63\x6b','\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74','\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x46\x75\x6c\x6c\x53\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6e','\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74','\x6d\x6f\x7a\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x46\x75\x6c\x6c\x53\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6e','\x77\x65\x62\x6b\x69\x74\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x46\x75\x6c\x6c\x53\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6e','\x41\x4c\x4c\x4f\x57\x5f\x4b\x45\x59\x42\x4f\x41\x52\x44\x5f\x49\x4e\x50\x55\x54','\x61\x6e\x69\x6d\x61\x74\x65','\x3c\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b\x20\x72\x65\x6c\x3d\x22\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3d\x22\x2f\x2f\x6d\x61\x78\x63\x64\x6e\x2e\x62\x6f\x6f\x74\x73\x74\x72\x61\x70\x63\x64\x6e\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x66\x6f\x6e\x74\x2d\x61\x77\x65\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x2f\x34\x2e\x33\x2e\x30\x2f\x63\x73\x73\x2f\x66\x6f\x6e\x74\x2d\x61\x77\x65\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x2e\x6d\x69\x6e\x2e\x63\x73\x73\x22\x3e\x20\x3c\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b\x20\x72\x65\x6c\x3d\x22\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3d\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3a\x2f\x2f\x63\x64\x6e\x6a\x73\x2e\x63\x6c\x6f\x75\x64\x66\x6c\x61\x72\x65\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d\x2f\x61\x6a\x61\x78\x2f\x6c\x69\x62\x73\x2f\x6e\x6f\x72\x6d\x61\x6c\x69\x7a\x65\x2f\x35\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x2f\x6e\x6f\x72\x6d\x61\x6c\x69\x7a\x65\x2e\x6d\x69\x6e\x2e\x63\x73\x73\x22\x3e\x20\x3c\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x3e\x20\x2f\x2a\x20\x4e\x4f\x54\x45\x3a\x20\x54\x68\x65\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x73\x20\x77\x65\x72\x65\x20\x61\x64\x64\x65\x64\x20\x69\x6e\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x20\x62\x65\x63\x61\x75\x73\x65\x20\x50\x72\x65\x66\x69\x78\x66\x72\x65\x65\x20\x6e\x65\x65\x64\x73\x20\x61\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x79\x6f\x75\x72\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x73\x20\x61\x6e\x64\x20\x74\x68\x65\x79\x20\x6d\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x69\x6e\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x64\x20\x69\x66\x20\x74\x68\x65\x79\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x6f\x6e\x20\x6c\x6f\x63\x61\x6c\x20\x64\x69\x73\x6b\x21\x20\x2a\x2f\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x7b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x69\x6e\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x2d\x62\x6c\x6f\x63\x6b\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x6c\x61\x62\x65\x6c\x20\x7b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x62\x6c\x6f\x63\x6b\x3b\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x32\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3a\x20\x32\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2d\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x6e\x74\x3a\x20\x2d\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x6c\x61\x62\x65\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x69\x20\x7b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x62\x6c\x6f\x63\x6b\x3b\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2d\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x6e\x74\x3a\x20\x30\x70\x78\x3b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x20\x7b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x6e\x6f\x6e\x65\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x58\x28\x30\x25\x29\x3b\x20\x62\x6f\x78\x2d\x73\x68\x61\x64\x6f\x77\x3a\x20\x30\x20\x30\x20\x33\x30\x70\x78\x20\x72\x67\x62\x61\x28\x30\x2c\x20\x30\x2c\x20\x30\x2c\x20\x30\x2e\x35\x29\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x20\x7b\x20\x6f\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79\x3a\x20\x31\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x58\x28\x30\x25\x29\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x31\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x69\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x58\x28\x30\x25\x29\x20\x72\x6f\x74\x61\x74\x65\x28\x33\x36\x30\x64\x65\x67\x29\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x32\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x31\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x33\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x31\x35\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x34\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x32\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x35\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x32\x35\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x36\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x33\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x37\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x33\x35\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x38\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x34\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74\x3a\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x20\x2b\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x39\x29\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2d\x64\x65\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x34\x35\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x7b\x20\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64\x3b\x20\x74\x6f\x70\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x6d\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6e\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x31\x30\x30\x76\x68\x3b\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3a\x20\x31\x35\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x6c\x69\x73\x74\x2d\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65\x3a\x20\x6e\x6f\x6e\x65\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x58\x28\x2d\x31\x30\x30\x25\x29\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x61\x6c\x6c\x20\x30\x2e\x32\x73\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x3b\x20\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x42\x35\x32\x42\x32\x42\x3b\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2d\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x6e\x74\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x62\x6f\x78\x2d\x73\x68\x61\x64\x6f\x77\x3a\x20\x30\x20\x30\x20\x33\x30\x70\x78\x20\x72\x67\x62\x61\x28\x30\x2c\x20\x30\x2c\x20\x30\x2c\x20\x30\x29\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x20\x7b\x20\x6f\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x58\x28\x2d\x31\x30\x30\x25\x29\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x61\x6c\x6c\x20\x30\x2e\x33\x73\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x30\x2e\x30\x35\x73\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x61\x20\x7b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x61\x20\x69\x20\x7b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x58\x28\x30\x25\x29\x20\x72\x6f\x74\x61\x74\x65\x28\x30\x64\x65\x67\x29\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x61\x6c\x6c\x20\x30\x2e\x35\x73\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x3a\x6e\x74\x68\x2d\x63\x68\x69\x6c\x64\x28\x31\x29\x20\x61\x3a\x68\x6f\x76\x65\x72\x20\x7b\x20\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x42\x35\x32\x42\x32\x42\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x20\x3e\x20\x61\x20\x7b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x62\x6c\x6f\x63\x6b\x3b\x20\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x72\x65\x6c\x61\x74\x69\x76\x65\x3b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x63\x6f\x6c\x6f\x72\x3a\x20\x23\x46\x46\x46\x3b\x20\x66\x6f\x6e\x74\x2d\x77\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x39\x30\x30\x3b\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2d\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x72\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x6e\x6f\x6e\x65\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x61\x6c\x6c\x20\x30\x2e\x31\x73\x20\x65\x61\x73\x65\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6e\x61\x76\x2d\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x20\x75\x6c\x20\x3e\x20\x6c\x69\x20\x3e\x20\x61\x3a\x68\x6f\x76\x65\x72\x20\x7b\x20\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x39\x34\x32\x41\x32\x41\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x7b\x20\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x3a\x20\x61\x62\x73\x6f\x6c\x75\x74\x65\x3b\x20\x74\x6f\x70\x3a\x20\x35\x30\x25\x3b\x20\x6c\x65\x66\x74\x3a\x20\x35\x30\x25\x3b\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x3a\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x6c\x61\x74\x65\x28\x2d\x35\x30\x25\x2c\x20\x2d\x35\x30\x25\x29\x3b\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2d\x61\x6c\x69\x67\x6e\x3a\x20\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x68\x31\x20\x7b\x20\x6d\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6e\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x36\x37\x65\x6d\x20\x30\x20\x30\x20\x30\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x69\x2e\x66\x61\x20\x7b\x20\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x3a\x20\x62\x6c\x6f\x63\x6b\x3b\x20\x6d\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6e\x3a\x20\x30\x20\x61\x75\x74\x6f\x3b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x62\x6f\x72\x64\x65\x72\x2d\x72\x61\x64\x69\x75\x73\x3a\x20\x35\x30\x25\x3b\x20\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x42\x35\x32\x42\x32\x42\x3b\x20\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x2d\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2d\x61\x6c\x69\x67\x6e\x3a\x20\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x3b\x20\x66\x6f\x6e\x74\x2d\x73\x69\x7a\x65\x3a\x20\x33\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x63\x6f\x6c\x6f\x72\x3a\x20\x77\x68\x69\x74\x65\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x69\x2e\x66\x61\x3a\x68\x6f\x76\x65\x72\x20\x7b\x20\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x39\x34\x32\x41\x32\x41\x3b\x20\x63\x6f\x6c\x6f\x72\x3a\x20\x77\x68\x69\x74\x65\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x63\x65\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x70\x20\x7b\x20\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x2d\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x31\x2e\x35\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x70\x6f\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x20\x7b\x20\x63\x75\x72\x73\x6f\x72\x3a\x20\x70\x6f\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x3b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3a\x20\x31\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x20\x7b\x20\x62\x61\x63\x6b\x67\x72\x6f\x75\x6e\x64\x3a\x20\x23\x39\x34\x32\x41\x32\x41\x3b\x20\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x31\x35\x65\x6d\x20\x30\x2e\x35\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x62\x6f\x72\x64\x65\x72\x2d\x72\x61\x64\x69\x75\x73\x3a\x20\x30\x2e\x32\x35\x65\x6d\x3b\x20\x7d\x20\x2e\x6a\x71\x2d\x74\x6f\x61\x73\x74\x2d\x77\x72\x61\x70\x2c\x2e\x6a\x71\x2d\x74\x6f\x61\x73\x74\x2d\x77\x72\x61\x70\x20\x2a\x7b\x6d\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6e\x3a\x30\x3b\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x3a\x30\x7d\x2e\x6a\x71\x2d\x74\x6f\x61\x73\x74\x2d\x77\x72\x61\x70\x7b\x64\x69\x73\ there was way more code but i couldent post it all

Answer (score 2):

Those are strings composed of ascii codes, represented in hexadecimal format.  You can use python to decode the strings, like so:

```
strings=['\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20','\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72','\x6b\x65\x79\x64\x6f\x77\x6e','\x6b\x65\x79\x43\x6f\x64\x65','\x6e\x67\x2d\x62\x69\x6e\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x2d\x6d\x69\x6e\x69\x20\x62\x74\x6e\x2d\x62\x6c\x75\x65\x20\x6c\x65\x76\x65\x6c\x62\x74\x6e\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68','\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65','\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6c\x65\x64','\x48\x41\x43\x4b\x45\x44\x20\x41\x43\x43\x4f\x55\x4e\x54\x53\x3a\x0a\x41\x52\x2d\x36\x37\x37\x37\x30\x20\x7e\x20\x53\x63\x72\x75\x62\x35\x39\x0a\x7a\x6f\x2d\x39\x38\x36\x30\x34\x20\x7e\x20\x62\x72\x69\x63\x6b\x31\x33\x0a\x6d\x64\x2d\x37\x30\x31\x35\x35\x20\x7e\x20\x64\x75\x63\x6b\x31\x34\x0a\x41\x4d\x2d\x31\x30\x34\x33\x31\x38\x38\x20\x7e\x20\x73\x61\x6e\x64\x36\x39\x0a\x4a\x4d\x2d\x36\x39\x37\x31\x37\x20\x7e\x20\x67\x6f\x61\x6c\x39\x37\x0a\x4d\x4b\x2d\x39\x30\x35\x38\x36\x20\x7e\x20\x73\x68\x61\x64\x65\x37\x37\x0a\x41\x50\x2d\x31\x30\x32\x38\x30\x31\x20\x7e\x20\x73\x6f\x69\x6c\x37\x30\x0a\x59\x65\x73\x20\x61\x6c\x6c\x20\x6f\x66\x20\x74\x68\x65\x6d\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6b\x20\x3a\x50\x20']
print(strings)
```

This produces:

```
['return ', 'addEventListener', 'keydown', 'keyCode', 'ng-binding btn btn-mini btn-blue levelbtnwidth', 'removeAttribute', 'disabled', 'HACKED ACCOUNTS:\nAR-67770 ~ Scrub59\nzo-98604 ~ brick13\nmd-70155 ~ duck14\nAM-1043188 ~ sand69\nJM-69717 ~ goal97\nMK-90586 ~ shade77\nAP-102801 ~ soil70\nYes all of them work :P ']
```